# Scrolling does not work on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll

I'm out of solution. My page wouldn't scroll on mobile devices (testing with iPhone 6).

Here is the structure

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <div id ="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The div "content" is about, 10000px height (lot of content)

Other pages, that does not include content, are scrolling perfectly.
So I think there is something with the overflow of the div content.

I tried overflow auto, scroll, height 100% height 100vh a lot of combinaison for html body and content but I can't get a proper solution that works both on computer and iPhone. Sometimes it's scrolling on iPhone but I have two scrollbars and my computer, sometime it is scrolling but the the header (which is supposed to fade away with headroom) stays here etc.

Any help is welcome. Thank you

http://liveweave.com/4gBZxB

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete reproduction of your problem? There's probably some CSS stuff at play here, and without a demo or reproducable code, its hard to figure out what could be going wrong without making a lot of shots in the dark.

Comment: Did you make sure to save your liveweave? That link takes me to a boilerplate liveweave page.

Comment: I did, try the new one ?

Comment: Alright, I copied your code from the new one into a basic webpage, then loaded it on my iPhone (6s, iOS 9.3). I'm having no trouble scrolling down the page. Same is true on desktop Chrome (51, on macOS), and desktop Safari.

Comment: Do you manage to get a smooth scrolling ? Like momentum one cause I don't$

Comment: Yes, I do. That being said, there is a bug with mobile webkit wherein you have to set a scrollable area to have the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` CSS property to restore that, if it isn't the body that is scrolling.

Comment: Problem solved. You show me the right path. It was't the CSS nor HTML but the JS. I used touchSwipe and it deactivates the page scroll by default ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was not the CSS nor HTML but the JS.

I used touchSwipe and it deactivates the page scroll by default on the div you applied a swipe event on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jquery.touchSwipe.js` for swipe, do add `allowPageScroll: "vertical"` to the swipe.

```
    $("#ID").swipe({
    -----------
    -----------
    threshold:100, 
    allowPageScroll: "vertical"
    });
```

it's working.